# Burninate [replace] tag?

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

[replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/replace) is described as

> Replacing is the action of searching a string (the haystack) for a
>   sub-string (the needle) and replacing it with a different string.
>
> So for example, replacing all 'l' within 'Hello' with 'y', would
>   result in 'Heyyo'.

Is it possible to be an expert in [replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/replace)? The newest page of the 10.6k tagged questions contains [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript), [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php), [ant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ant), [shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shell), and more.

Additionally, [replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/replace) is vague: although most questions are related to [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex), and are commonly tagged, [some](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26304707/1234256) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26282221/1234256) [like](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26258714/1234256) [these](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25930687/1234256) are unrelated.

On a side note, [replacing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/replacing) has already been burninated.

Comment: What about [the 24 questions that are tagged only with \[replace\]](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/201124#resultSets)? We may have to _replace_ those tags!

Comment: Waiting for someone to claim to be a [tag:replace] expert

Comment: Can we please just replace it?

Comment: anyways, I think for string replacements etc. it is an ok tag just like the "sum" tag, a subset of the tagged things might be ok, and some should be removed. I would decide on a case by case base.

Comment: Another tasteless joke: My free-time has been replaced by dealing with this tag.

Comment: @AeroX There was this guy who was so good at replace that he turned irreplaceable.

Comment: [tag:replace] isn't as dangerous as [tag:advice]

Comment: @Mooseman Err that's quite a radical edit. Is Meta different from other SE sites when it comes to editing rules?

Comment: @Lundin That's how I've always seen meta.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Who is an expert for replacing? Who searches for replace questions? What question could be clarified by this tag?

No one. No one. None.

Comment: It is me. It is me. Mine. You just don't know.

Answer (score 3):

Generally, I think you are correct, the tag should burn.

## But

The tag may have a home here.  There are many algorithms and implementations of replacing data in various structures (not just strings).  There are surely experts on the subject and there absolutely questions on the subject.

So as it stands now, the tag is useless, but it *could* be useful if it were tweaked ever so slightly to be about general data replacement *implementation*, not "How do I use Python's `str.replace()`."  Instead it should be "How can I design a custom replace method for X data structure."  For this example, someone who is God-King of the various search and replace algorithms could be very useful.

Change it or burn it, but it shouldn't be left as is

Comment: I think this would be better covered by somehting like replace-algorithm

Comment: Sounds like you're thinking of the [algorithm] tag, or even about a different SE site.

Comment: Oh, and the smart alec chimes in... shall we execute `comment[0] = comment[0].replace('ht', 'th');`