# Burninate [return]?

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

22 followers, 4.3k questions.
The [return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/return) tag seems to have no value. The tag wiki for it begins:

> A return statement causes execution to leave the current subroutine and resume at the point in the code immediately after where the subroutine was called, known as its return address. [...]

This seems about as useful as an [if](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/if) tag.

It's so generic as to be meaningless - for example, the first few questions with [return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/return) have additional tags covering the entire spectrum: [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript), [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23), [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python), [haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/haskell), [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c), [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery), [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php), etc.

I can't think of any utility or redeeming value for this tag.

Comment: Fairly courageous to disagree with over four thousand users.  Jon Skeet up front, he's got a badge for it.  This tag is entirely harmless of course, just a contextual tag.  All keywords in the programming languages in common use have a tag, [return] isn't special.

Comment: Who follows a tag like this? People who want to answer all the low quality questions by users who don't know how to tag their questions correctly?

Comment: @l4mpi s/answer/close/ (but that's a poor reason to keep a tag around).

Comment: @l4mpi: You don't think there are interesting language-neutral things related to returning?  Caller-vs-callee stack pointer adjustment in calling conventions. User-mode return vs return from interrupt vs return from syscall/gate.  Return address overwriting attacks (aka return-to-libc aka return-oriented-programming) as well as return address overwriting for flow control (used to implement fibers).  Error handling using return code vs global variables vs exceptions.  None of these are specific to a particular language.

Comment: "None of these are specific to a particular language" Actually, they all are.

Comment: I might ask which register the `return` keyword works with using Rust on ARM architectures. Your burninate request is invalid.

Comment: @HansPassant disagreeing with four thousand users with mostly crap questions (excluding Jon Skeet of course) is quite reasonable.

Comment: @BenVoigt I'm not saying that there are no interesting things to ask about `return`, but _that's not how the tag is being used_. I skimmed over the 50 newest questions yesterday, none had anything to do with the intricacies of return itself; the tag just indicates the OP has a problem loosely related to returning something. Also, most questions are from low-rep users (3 >100 rep, none >1k). I doubt users want to wade through that to find questions about return itself. As an analogy, cow dung _can_ be used as biofuel to generate electricity, but these people are just throwing it at each other.

Comment: @l4mpi: Ok, probably true. But then we need to separate the wheat from the chaff, not burn from orbit. Yuck.

Comment: @frasnian: No, they aren't. At least, no matter what language you say they are specific to, I can name a couple others.  More relevant is the CPU architecture - most of these are possible on most architectures, but the details are different.

Comment: @BenVoigt I don't see how that's possible as long as people, especially those new to the site, type plaintext sentences into the tag box and don't read tag wikis. Tags like those will always be misused and should IMO just be blacklisted (which will never happen because the process is apparently complicated); questions like the ones you mention can probably be asked under `language-design` and similar tags.

Comment: @BenVoigt The new users don't care about misusing tags, as long as they can use it and as long as there is no disincentive they will. It's more like finding needles in a haystack.

Comment: @BenVoigt Regarding your examples: 1) seems "calling-conventions" or sim. would be better 2) "interrupts" or sim. 3) you've mentioned some better examples already 4) "error-handling". This tag is just too broad to categorize a question in a useful way. If you see "c++" and "return" tags on a post, it can be on any or none of the examples you've provided. Such a broad range of diverse topics covered by a tag is unlikely to be helpful. Can you imagine someone that follows this tag because they like the mere concept of "returning" something, regardless of environment, architecture, language etc.?

Comment: what about [return value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/return-value) then, or [contains](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/contains), [replace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/replace), [equals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/equals)? (note: [another thread](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260435/burninate-replace-tag) exists on replace)